# How do I open this modal on timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a modal with CSS and HTML, but want to load it after 3 seconds on page load using jquery. I am having a hard time finding the right event handler for this. What is the best way to do this?

Modal below

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="about" class="target"></span>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="content" style="height: 425px;  width: 425px;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;margin-top: 50px;">Welcome back!</h2>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;">You left something in your cart.</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 43px; margin-top: 0px;"> Check out today!</p>
      <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
      <button class="cart-button" style="width: 189px;height: 49px;"> 
        View Cart</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-container">
   <p><a href="#about">Open Modal Window</a>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('time');
    }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: what js you are using for opening the modal

Comment: as far as i know JQUERY by it self does not have a modal visual. you need to use an extension (bootstrap for example)

Comment: _“I am having a hard time finding the right event handler for this”_ - how? You obviously found the load event already. Does that not achieve what you want? The load event fires when all external resources (stylesheets, images, etc.) have finished loading. If that is not what you want, then maybe you rather want the DOMContentReady event, or sth. like that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "load it after 3 seconds on page load"? Shall it automatically open after 3 seconds?

Comment: I am currently clicking to open the modal.  I need to create a modal without bootstrap sadly.

Comment: Yes, I want it to pop up automatically after 3 seconds

Comment: @CBroe He wants it to load 3 seconds after the page loads, not when the page loads. So far he has it right, he just needs to know the function to call to open the modal. I know when using bootstrap and jquery `$("#modalid").modal("show");` will show a modal but I'm not sure that would work with his modal.

Comment: _“I am currently clicking to open the modal”_ - then you must have more code than you have currently shown us - because nothing so far would actually achieve that. `<span id="about" class="target">` makes me _guess_ that your modal works via CSS, simply using the `:target` pseudo class to make the previously hidden modal visible. Depending on how it is hidden (display property, visibility property, ...) it should be trivial to change the appropriate CSS properties via JS. Or maybe just remove/set a class that makes it visible.

Comment: @Cbroe - Yes I did use target suedo class to open it originally. Should have added that in the OP. It is working now based on solutions below. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7pgrzp7d/

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.modal').modal({show:true});
}, 3000);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<span id="about" class="target"></span>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="content" style="height: 425px;  width: 425px;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;margin-top: 50px;">Welcome back!</h2>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;">You left something in your cart.</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 43px; margin-top: 0px;"> Check out today!</p>
      <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
      <button class="cart-button" style="width: 189px;height: 49px;"> 
        View Cart</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-container">
   <p><a href="#about">Open Modal Window</a>
 </div>
```

```
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.modal').modal({show:true});
  }, 3000);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions, I have hidden the modal via css (inline like your code), then after 3 seconds made it appear:

https://jsfiddle.net/pv7j5qdt/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('.modal').show();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="about" class="target"></span>
  <div class="modal" style="display: none;">
    <div class="content" style="height: 425px;  width: 425px;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;margin-top: 50px;">Welcome back!</h2>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;">You left something in your cart.</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 43px; margin-top: 0px;"> Check out today!</p>
      <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
      <button class="cart-button" style="width: 189px;height: 49px;"> 
        View Cart</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-container">
   <p><a href="#about">Open Modal Window</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: its quite strange there are at lest 3 questions in the last 23 hours based on same title please do not create duplication questions other different accounts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963426/how-do-i-open-this-modal-on-timeout/45963535?s=10|0.0000#45963535

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963426/how-do-i-open-this-modal-on-timeout/45963535?s=10|0.0000#45963535

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963426/how-do-i-open-this-modal-on-timeout?s=12|0.0000

Answer (score 0):

Well I added a class `hidden` and added it to the modal. Property is a `display:none;`. After 3 seconds I just remove this by using `show()`:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('div.modal').show();
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="about" class="target"></span>
  <div class="modal hidden">
    <div class="content" style="height: 425px;  width: 425px;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;margin-top: 50px;">Welcome back!</h2>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;">You left something in your cart.</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 43px; margin-top: 0px;"> Check out today!</p>
      <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
      <button class="cart-button" style="width: 189px;height: 49px;"> 
        View Cart</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-container">
   <p><a href="#about">Open Modal Window</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like these solutions, but feel I can add more after much mucking around and research. This applies to cases where there are more than a single modal on a particular page.
I found that the jquery solutions worked when there was only 1 modal, with the applicable classname.
And so, this was my problem:
using w3.css, all modals are class=w3-modal.
the snippet: $('.w3-modal').show();

My problem: I have more than 1 modal on the page.. This snippet will display all of them.

The solution is to give the modals all their own id - id="id1", id="id2", etc.
Then, instead of trying to get it to display via classname (the . in the snippet), we simply grab the modal by id.
This is achieved by using a (#) instead of a (.).
So:
the snippet: $('#id1').show();
or
the snippet: $('#id2').show();
n.b. always remember to add the jquery script reference too! This can cause many headaches in itself, especially when you are just still learning lol!

I know this was first answered over 5 years ago, but knowledge is timeless.

Cheers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).